# How to query a list of Bluetooth bonded (paired) devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to  display the list of bonded devices with the Android Bluetooth API, but I don't know why in this code when I run it on my device no toast is displayed? By the way, the toast will contain the name of each device.

```
package com.example.fatma.cst;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Vector;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txt = null;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Vector mArrayAdapter = null;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if(bluetoothAdapter==null){
            Toast t=new Toast(this);
            t.setText("Sorry your phone do not support Bluetooth");
            t.show();
        }
        else
        {
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }

            if(REQUEST_ENABLE_BT!=0) {



    /* bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        String action = intent.getAction();

                        //Finding devices
                        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());



                        }
                    }

                };*/

                //IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
               // registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
               Set<BluetoothDevice> devices;

                devices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                for (BluetoothDevice blueDevice : devices) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Device = " + blueDevice.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: I think your question is really about why Toast messages aren't displaying for you on your device.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method I use (and it's nothing special) to iterate and log or toast paired bluetooth devices.  Your code appears to be doing the same things.

```
void iterateBluetoothDevices() {
    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (btAdapter != null) {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        Log.i(LOGTAG, String.format("found %d bluetooth devices", (pairedDevices != null) ? pairedDevices.size() : 0));
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice d: pairedDevices) {
                String btID = String.format("bluetooth device [%s]  type: %s", d.getName(), d.getType());
                Log.i(LOGTAG, btID);
                Toast.makeText(this, btID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code by adding Toast in for loop.

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
// If there are paired devices
if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
// Loop through paired devices
for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
    // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
    mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
}
}
```

You can refer to this also [Bluetooth Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

Comment: Ok I'll try to find another solution